# Link to page describing using UTF8 as key in map tile generation?

Tags: maps

I wrote a blog posting on how to speed up map tile rendering (http://blog.webfoot.com/2013/03/12/optimizing-map-tile-generation/) and realized that I should credit a group for having a similar idea to my "skeletons" idea, but I can't find a reference to that idea now.

The idea that this group had was to represent pixels on a tile as an array of UTF8 characters, and then, when generating the tile image, looking up the appropriate attribute via the key of the UTF8 character, and from there assigning the right colour.  (I remember a text "image" of Scandinavia on the right-hand side of the page with different countries represented with $, %, etc.)

Unfortunately, if you do a Web search for "map UTF8", you get TONS of links about UTF8 character encodings, and another huge batch of links where HTML header code has leaked into the search target.

I believe this was part of one of the open source projects: Open Street Map or OSGeo or some such.  Alas, I can't find it by looking around on their sites.

Can anyone give me a link to the page describing using UTF8 characters as keys to look up attributes?

(I realize this is not a programming question *per se*, but programmers on maps are the people who will know the answer to this.  If there is a better place to post this, I'd be happy to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably talking about the [UTFGrid](http://mapbox.com/developers/utfgrid/) spec.

Anyway, nice blog post.

Comment: Yes!  Exactly, that was exactly what I was remembering and having trouble finding.  Thanks!  (And thanks for the compliment!)